# Wish: (re)Make a screenshot of already selected area again

Tags: unity, screenshot

My workflow:

1. I make a screenshot of an area via standard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>.
2. After I select the area, first screenshot is made and "gnome-screenshot" dialog window is shown.
3. While this dialog is opened, you can still see the area you have selected highlighted / shadowed. (When you close this dialog , highlighting disappear.)

I wish I can say to Ubuntu:

> Lets make screenshot of this the area again.
>   I don't want to redefine area. I only want another screenshot of the same area.

Advantages:

- Same size of screenshots.
- Quicker workflow.

Am I missing something or **is this feature missing**?

Comment: Thank you @dk-bose. This feature is (only) one feature which I'm missing in GNOME Screenshot so It will be really nice to that some developers will added it in there.
In the mean time I'm going to try the [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/), how _muru_ recommended it lower in his answer.

Comment: I miss ksnapshot, it used to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/). GNOME Screenshot is an okay tool, it covers the basics and is good enough for a default.

Shutter has a lot more functionality, but it also depends on more libraries. In particular, it has a redo option:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @muru. I'm going to try Shutter. But this feature is (only) one feature which I'm missing in GNOME Screenshot so It will be really nice to that some developers will added it there.

Comment: @MatějKříž you can file a [feature request](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=gnome-screenshot), but we all have that one missing feature that isn't implemented.